# Loop on checkBox only

Tags: winforms, linq

Can I loop on only checkboxes on my WinForm?

I would like to avoid this checking:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls())
    if (checkbox.GetType() == typeof (CheckBox))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Where` statement from `Linq` and a `Select` method to cast the control object to Checkbox, for sample:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls()
                             .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof (CheckBox))
                             .Select(c => (CheckBox)c))
{
   // code
}
```

Another way to go is use this:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
   // code
}
```

Comment: Why have I to use the select statement?

Comment: Just to convert the from `Control` type to `CheckBox` type. It is just to be safe, but you can do it without `Select` and let C# convert it for you implicity.

Comment: Thanks. I get the following error: `Window.Forms.Contorl cannot be used like a method.`

Comment: I edit my code and add another way to go, take a look

Comment: Thanks, but what is the detail I missed I got such an error? I also get this error using the second option: Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType'

Comment: @user3165438 - what version of .NET Framework you are using? you should add a reference to **System.Linq**

Comment: @KrishnrajRana, Thanks. I use .Net framewok4 client profile and for sure added the linq using.